# flutter nested json array of object parsing

Tags: json, dictionary, flutter, dart

Hi i am building an app and trying to parse nested array of object from an api call back and getting this error

Type String is not the sub Type of Map<String, dynamic>

Here is the model class

```
class Tournament {
  String id;
  String title;
  String roomID;
  String roomPass;
  String map;
  String type;
  String date;
  String time;
  int joined;
  String createdBy;
  List<UserIds> joinedUsers;

  Tournament(
      {this.createdBy,
      this.joinedUsers,
      this.id,
      this.date,
      this.map,
      this.roomID,
      this.roomPass,
      this.time,
      this.title,
      this.type,
      this.joined});

  factory Tournament.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['joinedUsers'] as List;
    List<UserIds> userList =
        list.map((data) => UserIds.fromJson(data)).toList();

    return Tournament(
        id: json['_id'],
        title: json['title'],
        roomID: json['roomId'],
        roomPass: json['roomPass'],
        map: json['mapType'],
        type: json['type'],
        date: json['date'],
        time: json['time'],
        joined: json['joined'],
        createdBy: json['createdBy'],
        joinedUsers: userList);
  }
}

class UserIds {
  String userId;

  UserIds({this.userId});

  factory UserIds.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return UserIds(userId: parsedJson['\$oid']);
  }
}
```

this is the json call back i got

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f1c47f2c3c051d9828b1697"
    },
    "joinedUsers": [{
        "$oid": "5f18621d6fca9d3e70a9fabe"
    }, {
        "$oid": "5f1a7609f7f69d2a1064e5ec"
    }],
    "title": "HomeComing",
    "date": "20-02-2020",
    "time": "8:22 Am",
    "roomId": "12345",
    "roomPass": "12223",
    "joined": {
        "$numberInt": "9"
    },
    "mapType": "Erangle",
    "type": "Dual",
    "createdBy": {
        "$oid": "5f16d9bde0fd621dec10e1c5"
    },
    "__v": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    }
}
```

now when i run this it gave me an error that type String is not the sub type of Map<String, dynamic>
i dont know what wrong i am doing right now

Comment: Please share where your `fromJson` constructors are **used** not just where they are defined. [Edit] the code directly into your question. Do not post it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try:

```
list.map((data) => UserIds.fromJson(JSON.parse(data)).toList();
```

Could be parse problems, you could log first your elements in your lambda by this to verify what it gives:

```
list.map((element) =>
{
  console.log(data);
  //UserIds.fromJson(JSON.parse(data)).toList();
});
```

Comment: can you tell what that JSON.parse come from i dont think its a function in dart

Comment: ok now i am getting this error `type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, void>' is not a subtype of type 'List<UserIds>')`

Comment: ok the data is printed in the console but the exception is thrown again `type 'List<void>' is not a subtype of type 'List<UserIds>'`

Comment: Can you print the data printed please, to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this example that I have made for userIds:
I have taken your json locally.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class UserIds {
  String userId;

  UserIds({this.userId});
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  List<UserIds> userIdsList = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
   
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    Map jsonData = json.decode(data);

    jsonData['joinedUsers'].forEach((item) {
      item.forEach((key, value) {
        print('This is the Key $key  value $value');
        userIdsList.add(UserIds(userId: value));
      });
    });

    print('This is the list ${userIdsList.length}');

   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Text(''));
  }
}
```